# I can't change JSON into a PHP array

Tags: php, arrays, json

For some strange reason I can't change the following JSON to a PHP array:

```
{"sides0":{"name_nl":"Voorkant100","name":"Frontside100","template_overlay":""},"sides1":{"name_nl":"Achterkant100","name":"Backside100","template_overlay":"1"}}
```

I've validated the json and it's valid.

First I post `$product['sides']` to my page, containing:

```
"{\"sides0\":{\"name_nl\":\"Voorkant100\",\"name\":\"Frontside100\",\"template_overlay\":\"\"},\"sides1\":{\"name_nl\":\"Achterkant100\",\"name\":\"Backside100\",\"template_overlay\":\"1\"}}"
```

Then I use json_decode on it like this:

```
$sidearr = json_decode($product['sides'], true);
```

If I then do:

```
echo '<pre>';
print_r($sidearr);
echo '</pre>';
```

It prints the first part of my question.

Now I want to loop over it, but even this test shows nothing:

```
foreach($sidearr as $side){
    echo 'test';
}
```

I tried testing if it even is an array with:

```
echo is_array($sidearr) ? 'Array' : 'not an Array';
echo "\n";
```

And it shows me that it is not an array. Why is that? I always thought using json_decode on a json string and add `true` inside the function turns it into a PHP array.

Comment: If `$product['sides']` contains the JSON as shown above then it should be working https://3v4l.org/mDqXh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It prints the first part of my question.

Because `$sidearr` is a string now, decode it again, you'll get an array.

```
$sidearr = json_decode($sidearr, true);
```